# Unexpected token React / JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

function WeatherApp() {

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
}, []);

const getWeather = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Krakow&appid=5eeb633dfbff4cd6c565e326670f0d0d&units=metric`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setWeather(data.weather);
}

return (
    <div className="main-cointainer">
        <form className="search-form">
            <input type="text" className="search-bar"/>
            <button type="submit" className="search-button" >Check</button>
        </form>
        <p>{weather}</p>
    </div>
);
```

}

I know there are simillar questions but I tried to manage it and didn't work. I'm really stucked and don't know how to solve this problem. I tried another port, put 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', changing my code for many diffrent ways but nothing. Network didn't show anything wrong, only console says "WeatherApp.jsx:16 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" after my getWeather const.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You are getting an HTML response, not a JSON response. Something is wrong in your API call. The headers are completely irrelevant. Looking at your url in a browser, looks like you're getting a 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the fetch url with the `https://` protocol:

```
const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Krakow&appid=5eeb633dfbff4cd6c565e326670f0d0d&units=metric`);
```

Comment: @JaredSmith I think you might be wrong. Tested on OSX Chrome. Same error as described when not adding protocol: https://jsfiddle.net/bgeqnz4s/

Comment: @JaredSmith The reason is that when you don't add a protocol, fetch will think the address is relative to your current page. It can't figure out if you meant fetching a full URL or a path relative to your page, and it will assume the later.